# endless loop when tkinter is used

Tags: python, tkinter, gis

I had a script which worked fine till I added a file query box for user interactivity. It keeps repeating the question and only quits if the following command (shutil.copy2) is forced to crash by making the in/output files the same. Why?

```
import os, xml, arcpy, shutil, datetime, Tkinter,tkFileDialog
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et 

path=os.getcwd()
RootDirectory=path
arcpy.env.workspace = path
Count=0

Generated_XMLs=RootDirectory+'\GeneratedXML_LOG.txt'
f = open(Generated_XMLs, 'a')
f.write("Log of Metadata Creation Process - Update: "+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
f.close()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(RootDirectory, topdown=False):
    #print root, dirs
    for directory in dirs:
        currentPath=os.path.join(root,directory)
        os.chdir(currentPath)
        arcpy.env.workspace = currentPath
        print currentPath
#def Create_xml(currentPath):

        FileList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        zone="_Zone"

        for File in FileList:
            Count+=1
            FileDesc_obj = arcpy.Describe(File)
            FileNm=FileDesc_obj.file
            print FileNm

            check_meta=os.listdir(currentPath)
            existingXML=FileNm[:FileNm.find('.')]
            existingExtension=FileNm[FileNm.find('.'):]
            print "XML: "+existingXML
            print check_meta
            #if  existingXML+'.xml' in check_meta:
            for f in check_meta:
             if f.startswith(existingXML) and f.endswith('.xml'):
                print "exists, file name:", f
                newMetaFile=FileNm+"_2012Metadata.xml"
                shutil.copy2(f, newMetaFile)
```

Code which causes the loop

```
     else:
        #print "Does not exist"
        newMetaFile=FileNm+"_BaseMetadata.xml"
        root = Tkinter.Tk()
        file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a xml base file to match with: '+File)
        if file != None:
             metafile=os.path.abspath(file.name)
             file.close()
             print metafile
             shutil.copy2(metafile,newMetaFile)
             print "copied"
        else:
        shutil.copy2('L:\Data_Admin\QA\Metadata_python_toolset\Master_Metadata.xml', newMetaFile)

    tree=et.parse(newMetaFile)        
    print "Processing: "+str(File)
```

Rest of working code

```
            for node in tree.findall('.//title'):
                node.text = str(FileNm)
            for node in tree.findall('.//northbc'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.extent.YMax)
            for node in tree.findall('.//southbc'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.extent.YMin)
            for node in tree.findall('.//westbc'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.extent.XMin)
            for node in tree.findall('.//eastbc'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.extent.XMax)        
            for node in tree.findall('.//native/nondig/formname'):
                node.text = str(os.getcwd()+"\\"+File)
            for node in tree.findall('.//native/digform/formname'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.featureType)
            for node in tree.findall('.//avlform/nondig/formname'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.extension)
            for node in tree.findall('.//avlform/digform/formname'):
                node.text = str(float(os.path.getsize(File))/int(1024))+" KB"
            for node in tree.findall('.//theme'):
                node.text = str(FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.name +" ; EPSG: "+str(FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.factoryCode))
            print node.text
            projection_info=[]
            Zone=FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.name

            if "GCS" in str(FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.name):
                projection_info=[FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.GCSName, FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.angularUnitName, FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.datumName, FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.spheroidName]
                print "Geographic Coordinate system"
            else:
                projection_info=[FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.datumName, FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.spheroidName, FileDesc_obj.spatialReference.angularUnitName, Zone[Zone.rfind(zone)-3:]]
                print "Projected Coordinate system"
            x=0
            for node in tree.findall('.//spdom'):
                for node2 in node.findall('.//keyword'):
                    print node2.text
                    node2.text = str(projection_info[x])
                    print node2.text
                    x=x+1


            tree.write(newMetaFile)

            f = open(Generated_XMLs, 'a')
            f.write(str(Count)+": "+File+"; "+newMetaFile+"; "+currentPath+"\n")
            f.close()



    #        Create_xml(currentPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has an indent error after the second else, but there are no loops unless one of the lists you iterate over is very, very large.  It may be a lot of copy operations that is taking the time (profiling will help).

Also, avoiding double negatives is desirable in Python and in English;
 if file != None:
 becomes if file:

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it by adding a break statement but now I am getting other issues -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090111/attributeerror-len-error-with-ntpath-py-an-tkinter-py which I don't understand as the os.path.join hasn't had any issues till now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your loop.

```
else:
        #print "Does not exist"
        newMetaFile=FileNm+"_BaseMetadata.xml"
         = Tkinter.Tk()
        file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a xml base file to match with: '+File)
        if file != None:
            =os.path.abspath(file.name)
            file.close()    
            print metafile
            shutil.copy2(metafile,newMetaFile)
            print "copied"
        else:
    shutil.copy2('L:\Data_Admin\QA\Metadata_python_toolset\Master_Metadata.xml', newMetaFile)

    tree=et.parse(newMetaFile)        
    print "Processing: "+str(File)
```

Here at at the end you want to say:

```
break
```

That will end the loop

Or you can use this(example)

```
x=0
for y in z:
    x+=1
if x == 20:
    break
```

that will run the loop 20 times
Oh and after the second else you need to indent.

Answer (score -2):

Had to add a break statement so that it got out of the loop.

Comment: Please don't provide updates in the answer section -- this isn't a discussion forum. If you want to provide a _complete_ answer that shows what you did, that's fine. However, a one line summary doesn't really help anyone who might have the same problem.